# Usage of props in react-native

Tags: react-native

Good afternoon,
I don't understand why we use **props** near the **onShowModal()** which is placed down the **else if statement of the function RenderCampsite**. I was thinking maybe it can be used because we have props as an argument of the function RenderCampsite, but I am not sure.
Please if somebody can give some orientation about it I will appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

```
function RenderCampsite(props){
    const {campsite} = props; 

     const view = React.createRef(); 

     const recognizeComment = ({dx})=> (dx > 200) ? true : false;

    const recognizeDrag = ({dx})=>(dx < -200) ? true : false;

    const panResponder = PanResponder.create({  
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder:()=> true,
      onPanResponderGrant: ()=> { 
        view.current.rubberBand(1000)
        .then(endState=> console.log(endState.finished ?  'finished' : 'canceled'));
        },
      onPanResponderEnd:(e, gestureState)=> { 
        console.log('pan responder end', gestureState);
        if(recognizeDrag(gestureState)){ 
          Alert.alert( 
            'Add Favorite',
            'Are you sure you wish to add' + campsite.name + 'to favorite ?',
            [
              { 
                text: 'Cancel', 
                style: 'cancel', 
                onPress: ()=> console.log('Cancel pressed')
               },
               { 
                 text: 'OK', 
                 onPress: ()=> props.favorite ? 
                 console.log('Already set as a favorite') : props.markFavorite()
                }
            ],
            { cancelable: false}
           );
         }
         else if(recognizeComment(gestureState)){
           props.onShowModal();
         }
         return true;
      }
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you call the function `RenderCampsite()` make sur to pass an object with the "campsite" property like this way :

```js
function RenderCampsite(props) {
    const {campsite} = props; 
    console.log(campsite) //will retrun "seomething" in this example
}


RenderCampsite({campsiteeee: "something"})
```

in your code the campsite object need to have a name property so it should look like this :

```js
function RenderCampsite(props) {
    const {campsite} = props; 
    console.log('Are you sure you wish to add ' + campsite.name + ' to favorite ?')
}


RenderCampsite({campsite: {name: "example name"}})
```

and yes the "props" is just an argument of the function

Comment: Thank you so much Wawa I appreciate your kind help,  you have helped me to understand more about props.  Have a Blessed day !!!